# Sendgrid - How to set the 'Content-Transfer-Encoding' to '7bit'

Tags: nodes, sendgrid

Using Sendgrid, emails with dynamic templates are sent in Node.js using [sendgrid-nodejs](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/master/packages/mail) package.

The emails sent to Outlook emails id have formatting issues and Sendgrid has recommended changing the MIME settings by setting the `'Content-Transfer-Encoding'` to `'7bit'` instead of `'Quoted-Printable'`([Sendgrid documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/formatting-html/)) but did not mention how we can achieve this.

Also, I did not find any MIME settings on the Sendgrid dashboard.